# Android: an activity with no ability to back to it

Tags: android, android-activity

when my app runs first time an authentication activity run and in other cases it does not show.

I want this activity just runs once and after that delete from back button stack.
I don't want to back to this activity by pressing back button.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When You start another Activity just `finish()` the first one

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
 finish();
```

method in your second Activity after on back pressed

So it will never goes to that Activity.